# In "The Machine" (2013), why is a soldier burned?

Tags: the-machine

In the 2013 movie [The Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Machine_%28film%29), when Ava first goes to the base, a soldier gets burned alive by the cyborgs, why did that happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's *very* hard to catch, but if you listen carefully starting at about 14:10 (where Suri is sitting at her security console and suddenly looks up) you can follow the audio feeds that Suri is listening to. At about 14:20 you can see and hear one of the implanted soldiers saying (to another implant) something like "...she trusts me...she's plotting a revolution. We have to stop her...". Those two guards are the ones Suri later puts "on trial". The one who said "...she trusts me..." is the one she burned. I'm not sure, but I think the other guard was knifed (though I may be wrong about that).

Comment: It just occurred to me, this scene also tells us that the implanted soldiers still have free will, that the implants don't turn them into mere extensions of the central machine.

Comment: this _was_ very hard to catch, thanks!